# Casting Classes and Setting Common Values

Tags: c#, class, type-conversion

We have a series of classes, which are derived from a common class:

```
public class OurBaseClass
{
    public string StatusMessage { get; set;}
    [other properties]
}

public class ProcessClass : OurBaseClass
{
    public string SomeProcessInformation { get; set;}
    public string SomeMoreProcessInformation { get; set;}
    [other properties]
}
```

We are then trying to create a single function to set the basic properties of the SpecificProcessClass and current have (which doesn't work):

```
public object DefaultResponse(string messageText)
{
    return new OurBaseClass
    {
        StatusMessage = messageText,
        [other properties] = ...
    }
};
```

With the intention that we could have

```
ProcessClass resp = (ProcessClass) DefaultResponse("Some Message");
resp.SomeProcessInformation  = "";
resp.SomeMoreProcessInformation  = "";
[other properties] = ...
return resp;
```

The reasoning, is to minimise the amount of repeated coding and make the functions easy to read (by eye); this is throwing an error for the following.

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'OurBaseClass' to type 'ProcessClass'
```

Whilst not entirely surprised at the result, as the ProcessClass is derived from OurBaseClass, I would assume that it IS possible to do this, just not sure how...

Comment: It is not possible to to cast an instance of a base-class(less specific class) to an instance of a derived class(more specific class) because the derived class could/should have more functionality than the base class. The other way around works just fine, you can cast an instance of a derived class to an instance of the base class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't cast from a less derived type to a more derived type, you need to create that more derived type in the first place.

One solution similar to your current code is to use generics:

```
public T DefaultResponse<T>(string messageText)
    where T : OurBaseClass, new()
{
    return new T
    {
        StatusMessage = messageText,
    };
}
```

The `where` constraints restrict `T` to `OurBaseClass` or a derived type, and `new()` means that `T` must have a parameterless constructor.  You can read more about them [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

It can be used like so:

```
ProcessClass resp = DefaultResponse<ProcessClass>("Some Message");
resp.SomeProcessInformation  = "";
resp.SomeMoreProcessInformation  = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a method in the base class to set the common properties, and then having a virtual method that can be overrridden in the sub classes with each one calling the base method.

```
public class OurBaseClass
{
    public string StatusMessage { get; set;}
    // other properties

    protected void BaseInit()
    {
        // Set common properties here...
    }

    public virtual void Init()
    {
        BaseInit();
    }

}

public class ProcessClass : OurBaseClass
{
    public string SomeProcessInformation { get; set;}
    public string SomeMoreProcessInformation { get; set;}

    public override void Init()
    {
        BaseInit();

        // Set specific properties here...
    }
}
```